# Graph of correlated words

Tags: python, graph, correlation, text-mining

I'm reading about techniques for text mining and found an interesting graph showing correlated words using R. This can be found in section 9.2.1 Finding tf-idf within newsgroups of this page: http://tidytextmining.com/usenet.html#pre-processing-text.

I uses the

```
library(ggraph)
library(igraph)
```

libraries.

I'm wondering if Python provides a similar method to generate this kind of plot.